# How to add a datepicker into Django ModelFrom?

Tags: python, django, datepicker, django-templates

These are my scripts -

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Leave(models.Model):
    ...
    from_date = models.DateField()
    to_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I wanted to have datepickers for the above `DateField`(s).

This is my form template:-

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <h3>  Fill out the form please! </h3>
    <h4>
        <form action="." role="form", method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}

            {{ form.as_p }}

            <button type = "submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </h4>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

So far, what i have done - 
I have included this in my `base.html`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
</script>
```

In my forms.py as I'm using ModelForms, I have included this code  -

```
class LeaveRequestForm(ModelForm): 
    class Meta:
        fields = ("from_date", "to_date")
        model = Leave

        widgets =  {

            'from_date' : DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}),
            'to_date' : DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}),

        }
```

But no datepicker is being reflected in my html template. I have read many other question related to this but couldn't understand. Hope, anyone explains me in detail.

base.html

```
...
<html>
  <head>
    ...

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    ...

  </head>
```

Comment: In your `attrs`, you're passing the same `id` for two different date elements, `from_date` and `to_date`. I would remove the explicit `id` definition, and Django will automatically assign `id_from_date` and `id_to_date` to the fields. Then open your browser's developer tools and look for JavaScript errors in the console.

Comment: @FlipperPA yet nothing happens. `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at bootstrap.min.js:6` all i found is this only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is correct. However, from your comment it looks like you're using Bootstrap. You need to import Jquery **BEFORE** `bootstrap.min.js` and not after. If you have a javascript error in your page, it will prevent the datepicker from working.